# difference between two web works website

Tags: blackberry-webworks

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/widgetapi/

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/webworks/api/playbook/

can anyone point out y thy got two websites ? ..

does webworks support both ??

Answer (score 1):

The first link redirects to the second one.

The widget api was a way develop using web tools and the traditional Java SDK. Now all their efforts are with WebWorks which accomplished the same.

You can use web tools with WebWorks directly, like JQuery or Google Gears, and you can still create ports to acces the Java SDK in you mobile phone (there is no Java SDK for PlayBook yet).

With WebWorks, building apps for the Blackberry devices is like building standard WebApps. Knowledge of Java is not needed.